# C# with "something" does not contain a constructor that takes '2' arguments

Tags: c#

Dear all kindly members of this site.

I am a pretty new programmer with C# and I tried to implement a Database project using C#.

Below is an extract of the 'TableInfo.cs' file (namespace is 'AdministrativeDataTransfer')

When I try to build the solution there's a compiler error:

> 'AdministrativeDataTransfer.AttributeCI' does not contain a
>   constructor that takes '2' arguments;

Given the source code shown below, how could I solve it ?

```
            //attributes of element type
            for (int i = 0; i<complexType.Attributes.Count; i++)
            {
                if (complexType.Attributes[i] is XmlSchemaAttribute)
                {
                    ColumnInfo ci = new AttributeCI((XmlSchemaAttribute)complexType.Attributes[i],this);
                    m_lstColumns.Add(ci);
                    m_tblColumns.Add(ci.ElementName, ci);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new NotSupportedException();
                }
            }
```

Comment: We need the source to AttributeCI the problem is that that has the wrong constructor given how you are calling it here

Comment: You cannot learn a programming language with questions and answers. You need to start with reading a book.

Comment: did you run this program while debugging? if so, where did you get stuck. my thinking is that this part of cofe is not workging:  m_tblColumns.Add(ci.ElementName, ci); are you ure you can add a Elementname and some columnInfo to m_tblColumns?

Comment: w0lf, thanks for the edits. I also got rid of the salutations in the end and added the C# tag.

Comment: @TOUY VINATH: As Luke said, you need to post the code for the AttributeCI class.

Comment: @Moonlight I wouldn't think so, that would include the list/map thing of m_tblColumns in the error. Probably the constructor in AttributeCI does not accept two parameters (expects either, 0-1 or 3-x). But as said frequently, please post the constructor code of AttributeCI.cs.

I have also retagged your question to C# only, this has nothing to do with the if-statement.

A final tip, in the programming world 'something' is often replaced with "Foo" and "bar"'s :)

Answer (score 1):

this line is the problem

```
ColumnInfo ci = new AttributeCI
                (
                    (XmlSchemaAttribute)complexType.Attributes[i],
                    this
                );
```

The `AttributeCI` class does not have a constructor that accepts two parameters. Either implement the constructor you want or change the instantiation.